# Need to Open an Intent from a String Source

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am facing a challenge here. I created a list (in a listView) and when I choose an item (of this list) it returns a string. I need open a new screen with this string.

Let me try to explain: this list contains the following (only a tiny part shown here):

```
"ACTION_SETTINGS", "ACTION_SHOW_REGULATORY_INFO", "ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS", "ACTION_STORAGE_VOLUME_ACCESS_SETTINGS", "ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS",
"ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS", "ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS", "ACTION_USER_DICTIONARY_SETTINGS"  blablabla...
```

Actually is there more than one hundred options like the above options. These options are specific configuration options. So when I click one of this options it should open the "specific config screen".

If I do this way it works, but what I want is choose from the list and and not this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

// above is a "static" way to do this (but works)

what I want is a "dynamic" way to do this.

Something like:

```
String novaTela = "android.provider.Settings."  + listaConf.getItemAtPosition( i ).toString();
// above listaConf is my ListView
Intent intent = new Intent(novaTela);
```

I already tried to parse but never works. something like this:

```
Intent intent = Intent.parseIntent(sIntent); // I don't know it is possible
```

if I use with "fixed arguments" like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

that works... but if I try my "dynamic" way like this:

```
    String novaTela = "android.provider.Settings." + listaConf.getItemAtPosition( i ).toString(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(novaTela);
```

I get an error:

> No activity Found to handle Intent
>   {act=android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_OPTIONS}

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Hey Flavio, welcome to SO! I feel you could improve a bit your question by adding the error you are getting, just by looking at your code I don't see any issues. What line is the one that is failing? What is the actual error? Thanks!

Comment: if I use with "fixed arguments" like this:
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
that works...
but if I try my "dinamic" way like this:
String novaTela = "android.provider.Settings."  + listaConf.getItemAtPosition( i ).toString();
// above listaConf is my ListView
Intent intent = new Intent(novaTela);
it gives me the ERROR:
No activity Found to handle Intent {act=android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_OPTIONS}    Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What actually you got from this line

```java
String setting = android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS;
```

is

```java
"android.settings.SETTINGS"
```

It is OK to pass it into `Intent` directly:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
```

So this should fix your problem:

```java
String novaTela = listaConf.getItemAtPosition( i ).toString().replace("ACTION_","android.settings."); 
Intent intent = new Intent(novaTela);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But as I said, if I give a fixed value like you suggest, it works... What I need is to open FROM the list... open the setting i choose from list.

Comment: Edited my answer. See the last past.

Comment: Hello. That really works. But as you see, I have a huge list, taken from androiddeveloper web site. I'll need to edit it... something like ACTION_SOUND_OPTIONS  change to android.settings.SOUND_SETTINGS
this change, in entire list.....

Comment: Did you actually read my last updated answer? If not, please refresh your browser page. In there, I use `replace()` method. You don't need to edit your list now.

Comment: Pay attention to these line:

Comment: `String novaTela = listaConf.getItemAtPosition( i ).toString().replace("ACTION_","android.settings."); 
Intent intent = new Intent(novaTela);`

Comment: dguy you saved my week. Thank you very much. I really haven't refreshed the browser. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: dguy some configs doesn't work this way. For example :

ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT

works --> Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT);

doesn't work  --->   Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT");

Any ideia ?

Comment: Let me know more examples of them that don't work so I can fix my answer to work for all.

Comment: please email - me flaviocwbpr@gmail.com and I'll sent you the project. Is really tiny. Thank you

Comment: Has sent. Check your Inbox.

Comment: I have posted the final solution that my friend dguy developed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, my friend Myo (dguy) helpeed me and found the final solution. Code follows:

```
 // adiciona o clique na lista
        listaConf.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                // current String from your list
                String current = listaConf.getItemAtPosition( i ).toString();
                /* pega o item selecionado na ListView */
                txtConf.setText(current);
                try{

                // By java refelection, get the actual String from "android.provider.Settings" class to pass into Intent
                Field f = android.provider.Settings.class.getField(current);
                String setting = (String)f.get(null);
                /* passa o item para a Intent */
                Intent intent = new Intent(setting);
                /* bloco para evitar que o app pare por erro */

                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e ){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERRO: " + e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

That worked the way I need, and I'm posting it because maybe can be usefull to someone.
Thaks again Myo (dguy)